# Unnest array values from multiple columns with dynamic unpivot

Tags: postgresql, query, normalization, array

I have been given several tables in wide form that I would like to convert to long form. Unfortunately, they have about 60 columns.

Example input:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_wide (
    p_key integer PRIMARY KEY,
    col_a integer,
    col_b integer,
    col_c integer);
    
INSERT INTO tbl_wide (p_key, col_a, col_b, col_c)
VALUES (1,10,20,30),(2,50,10,5);
```

| p_key | col_a | col_b | col_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| 2 | 50 | 10 | 5 |

Desired output:

| f_key | col | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 10 |
| 1 | b | 20 |
| 1 | c | 30 |
| 2 | a | 50 |
| 2 | b | 10 |
| 2 | c | 5 |

Unnesting the arrays produces the correct result:

```
SELECT p_key as f_key,
        unnest(array['a','b','c']) col,
        unnest(array[col_a, col_b, col_c]) val
FROM tbl_wide
```

However, given the number of columns and tables to convert I would like to use a reference table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_reference (
    col_identifier text primary key,
    list_of_cols text);
    
INSERT INTO tbl_reference (col_identifier, list_of_cols)
VALUES ('a','col_a'),('b','col_b'),('c','col_c');
```

| col_identifier | list_of_cols |
| --- | --- |
| a | col_a |
| b | col_b |
| c | col_c |

So my query becomes something like:

```
SELECT p_key as f_key,
        unnest((SELECT array_agg(col_identifier) FROM tbl_reference)) col,
        unnest((SELECT array_agg(list_of_cols) FROM tbl_reference)) val
FROM tbl_wide
```

However, I can't figure out how to unnest the column values. The column names as strings are returned instead:

| f_key | col | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | col_a |
| 1 | b | col_b |
| 1 | c | col_c |
| 2 | a | col_a |
| 2 | b | col_b |
| 2 | c | col_c |

The following works but I the point is I want to avoid having to write out the column names each time:

```
SELECT p_key as f_key,
        unnest((SELECT array_agg(col_identifier) FROM tbl_reference)) col,
        unnest(array[col_a, col_b, col_c]) val
FROM tbl_wide
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
SELECT p_key AS f_key, col_identifier AS col, val::int
FROM tbl_wide
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(tbl_wide) - 'p_key') AS un(col_name, val)
  JOIN tbl_reference ON col_name = list_of_cols
  ORDER BY f_key, col;
```